# Check if datetime value is from last 30 days in php (not in the mysql query)?

Tags: php

I need to check with php if values got from a database are from last 30 days.

The values are formatted as follows:

```
2012-03-19 05:00:32
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = '2012-03-19 05:00:32';
if (strtotime($date) >= strtotime('-30 days')) {
    // do something
}
```

See [strtotime() reference](http://php.net/strtotime).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to turn it to a unix timestamp.

```
$db_date = "2012-03-19 05:00:32";
if (time() - strtotime($db_date) <= 30 * 86400) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in PHP, but that'd mean a roundtrip through the date/time system to process that string back into a date value:

```
$within_30 = ((strtotime('2012-03-19 05:00:32') + 30*86400) > time());
```

Assumign you're using MySQL, you could do it in the query directly, and save some time conversions:

```
SELECT ((yourtimefield + INTERVAL 30 DAY) > now()) AS within_30 ...
```